# Incrementing and evaluating dates in SAS

Tags: sas

I have the following variables:

```
%let curr_score_date = '31DEC2013'D; 
%let target_date = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&curr_score_date,12,e));
%let prod_start_date = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&curr_score_date,-11,b));
%let prod_end_date = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&curr_score_date,0,e));
```

If evaluating based on [this documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm), I evaluate each statement on its own to:

```
target_date = '31Dec2014'
prod_start_date = '01Jan2013'
prod_end_date = '31Dec2013'
```

However, I am wondering if each step just returns a value, or actually updates &curr_score_date. If it was updated at each calculation, this would certainly affect the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SAS, `functions` return values (and cannot change their arguments), while `call routines` can change their arguments.

As such, in the above, `&curr_score_date` cannot be changed by use of `%sysfunc`.